# Error R6025 on add Line on Invoice Document - SAP DiApi

Tags: java, invoice, sapb1, sap-business-one-di-api, r6025

While integrating invoices into SAP in my Java application on Windows, I am having the following error "R6025 - Pure virtual function call".
However, my application runs on multiple clients in a single version and I have no problems with any of the clients, just this specific one!

During testing with the application in the client environment, I noticed that the error always happens when using the "add" to add the first line in the invoice.

```
invoiceV1.getLines().add(); // The error happens here!
System.out.println("THIS LINE NOT APPEARS ON CMD");
invoiceV1.getLines().setCurrentLine(lineNum);

............ SETTING LINE VALUES ..........

lineNum++;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, you don't need to set the `.add()` on the first line. Try to put an `if` just to check if it is the first line or not.

If that doesn't work, you could consider an enviroment error? Or some instalattion problem?

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, tried to carry out the following changes:

if (lineNum> 0) {
      invoiceV1.getLines (). add ();
      invoiceV1.getLines (). setCurrentLine (lineNum);
}

........................... AND ...........................

if (lineNum> 0) {
      invoiceV1.getLines (). add ();
}
invoiceV1.getLines (). setCurrentLine (lineNum);

Comment: That was also it, but there were some flaws in the client environment!